# changing adress of char array inside a function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm playing with pointers and array and I found it hard to understand why this code doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void change(char **test)
{
    char *test1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*17);  
    strcpy(test1, "HEAP");

    *test = test1;

}

int main()
{
    char str[15]= "hello World";    //Array of char
    change(&str);   // Passing the address of my array of char
    printf("%s", str);
}
```

The goal is to change the address of `str`to the allocated memory array inside the function `change`

But changing the line :

```
char str[15]= "hello World";
```

to this (which is read only right ?):

```
char *str= "hello World";
```

Also, I'm getting a warning when compiling that I don't understand either :

```
main.c:17:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘change’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   17 |     change(&str);   // Passing the address of my array of char
      |            ^~~~
      |            |
      |            char (*)[15]
main.c:5:20: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[15]’
    5 | void change(char **test)
```

Thank you !

Comment: `char str[15]` isn't a pointer so you can't change its address. Do `char orig[15]= "hello World";  char *str = orig;` and then you'll be able to change what `str` points at.

Comment: That’s what I was trying to avoid using another pointer to achieve the same goal. Bu I was wrong and I think I get it now, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char str[15]` isn't a pointer so you can't change its address. You need `str` to be a `char*`.

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HEAP "HEAP"

void change(char **test)
{
    char *test1 = malloc(sizeof HEAP); // sizeof(char) is defined to be 1
    strcpy(test1, HEAP);
    *test = test1;
}

int main()
{
    char orig[] = "hello World";
    char *str = orig;          // initialize it to point at the first char in orig
    printf("before: %s\n", str);
    change(&str);
    printf("after : %s\n", str);
    free(str);                 // free what you've allocated
}
```

Comment: Thank you, as I said I could have used a pointer to the array and directly modify it, but my bad I miss explained what I was trying to do. The thing was that an array cannot change address

Comment: @Liwinux _"an array cannot change address"_ - Exactly! You're welcome!

Comment: Because if they do, then it’s stupid as we lost the allocated array during compilation right ?

Comment: @Liwinux Sort of I guess. All automatic (stack allocated) variables are _fixed_ in memory. They are placed on the stack and then automatically removed when the stack unwinds.

Comment: That explains the lvalue then…

Answer (score 1):

> *The goal is to change the address of `str`to the allocated memory array inside the function change...*

You cannot change the address of a variable. If a variable is a non-const pointer, you can make it point to some other memory address, provided it should be of compatible type with the type of pointer.

Before moving ahead, a couple of points for array:

- Arrays are not pointers. They both are different.
- In C, array names are non modifiable lvalues.

The warning message that you are getting is very clearly conveying the message - the type of argument that you are passing to `change()` function is not compatible with type of its parameter. The type of `&str` argument (passing to `change()`) is `char (*)[15]` and type of `test` parameter is `char **`.

Lets change the type of `test` parameter of `change()` function and make it compatible with the type of `&str` that you are passing to `change()` function and check what happens!
Make the following change in your program

```
void change(char (*test)[15])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

With this change when you compile your program, you will get following error:

```
#  gcc -Wall -Wextra prg.c
prg.c:10:11: error: array type 'char [15]' is not assignable
    *test = test1;
    ~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
```

The error is occurring because `test` is a pointer pointing to `str` array and when you dereference it (i.e. `*test`) you get the array of type `char [15]` and, that means, this statement will end up attempting to assign `test1` to array of type `char [15]` (which, in this context, is array `str`). Check the second point above - array names are non modifiable lvalues. Hence, this error is occurring.

So, arrays are non assignable, however, you can change the content of array in `change()` function using the address of `str` that you passing to `change()` function. You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_CHARS 15

void change(char (*test)[NUM_CHARS]) {
    strcpy (*test, "HEAP");
}

int main (void) {
    char str[NUM_CHARS]= "hello World";    //Array of char

    printf ("Before calling change(), str : %s\n", str);
    change (&str);   // Passing the address of my array of char
    printf ("After calling change(), str : %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
Before calling change(), str : hello World
After calling change(), str : HEAP
```

Note, that same you can achieve with passing the `str` to `change()` function, instead of passing address of `str` (Of course, you have to make respective changes in the `change()` function as well).

How to make a pointer pointing so some other memory inside a function is already shown in other post (by @Ted Lyngmo).

---

Follow good programming practice:

- Always check the `malloc()` return.
- Make sure to free the dynamically allocate memory once done with it.

Comment: So because the array I a const pointer, I can’t change its address right ? Therefore it’s a non modifiable lvalue? So if I understand correctly an array is a different type of variable hence why I get a warning

Comment: I think that my problem was that for me writing char test[15] was kind of a shortcut to write char *test. But I was wrong. I guess it makes sense for it to be a non modifiable lvalue, because if we do then we actually lost the allocated array during the compilation process which is stupid. I actually don’t know what to write as a parameter to my function as I said that for me an array was a pointer, but now I get it, they are both two different type of variable